# AWS Cross Account Load Balancing Via Transit Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to set up cross account load balancing on AWS (We're using the Landing Zone Accelerator). The situation is as follows.

Account A is our Network Management account where I want to have a public facing load balancer that routes user traffic to account B.

Account B is where my EC2 instances are in Private Subnets. All of our sub accounts for clients/end user apps are connected back to Account A via Transit Gateway attachments. There is one single Internet Gateway in Account A with 3 NAT Gateways split across 3 Availability Zones (3 public subnets with NAT's, 3 private subnets with ENI's) for High Availability, this provides Account B with Internet Access for our private instances.

Routing is configured as working as we've successfully reached the internet from our private EC2's in Account B and can ping ENI's in Account A. At the moment I'm struggling to get the health checks to show as healthy and I'm not sure why. I've tried a NLB and an ALB.

Has anyone got this working before, if so, how?!

TIA

I expected the load balancer to have healthy checks as routing is working

Comment: What happens if you put an EC2 instance in a subnet used by your public-facing load balancer in Account A and try to reach one of your private instances? This will be the closest approximation to what the load balancer is doing and should help you debug.